# jquery Mobile - Add Option to expand / collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to take a dynamic data-role="list-divider" and make it collapsible. This works fine to display a long list of "Customers" divided by their "Status"

How do I add in a toggle button that "Expands All/Collapses All" ?
Here is my ColdFusion code below & the JavaScript code.

I'm using this jsfiddle sample to create my page: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5PnBT/50/

```js
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page-wrapper", function() {
  $("#com-status-value").listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function(li) {
      var out = li.attr('status');
      return out;
    }
  }).listview('refresh');

  var ic = '<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus dividerIcon">&nbsp;</div>'
  $(".ui-li-divider").prepend(ic);
  $(".dividerIcon").addClass("divIconPos");
});

$(document).on("click", '.ui-li-divider, .dividerIcon', function(e) {
  var IsCollapsed = true;
  var TheDivider = $(this);
  if ($(this).hasClass('dividerIcon')) {
    TheDivider = $(this).parents('.ui-li-divider');
  }

  var li = TheDivider.next(':not(.ui-li-divider)');
  while (li.length > 0) {
    IsCollapsed = li.css('display') == 'none';
    li.toggle();
    li = li.next(':not(.ui-li-divider)');
  }

  if (!IsCollapsed) {
    TheDivider.find('.dividerIcon').removeClass('ui-icon-minus').addClass('ui-icon-plus');
  } else {
    TheDivider.find('.dividerIcon').removeClass('ui-icon-plus').addClass('ui-icon-minus');
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.ui-li-divider {
  padding-left: 28px;
}

.divIconPos {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="false" id="page-wrapper">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Open FFO Orders
      <cfoutput>(#rsCOM.recordcount#)</cfoutput>
    </h1>
    <a href="" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Expand</a>

  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-filter="true">
    <ul id="com-status-value" data-inset="false" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
      <cfoutput query="rsCOM" group="status">
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-filter="true">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;#rsCOM.status#
        </li>
        <cfoutput>
          <li>
            <p>#custAddress# #cc#, #st# #zp#</p>
            <p>Last Modified: #LmMb# </p>
          </li>
        </cfoutput>
      </cfoutput>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] when you create a snippet. That means no CF or other templates - the issue is JS and not CF

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

- add a button `Expands All/Collapses All` maybe a meaningful icon
- add an event listener for the button
- on click (tap) check if any of items is collapsed, if yes then expand all, if no then collapse all

*HTML*

```
<input type="button" id="expand-collapse" value="Expands All/Collapses All" />
```

*JavaScript*

```
var $listItems = $('#hp-latest-articles li:not(.ui-li-divider)');

$('#expand-collapse').on("click", function () {

    if ($('#hp-latest-articles li:not(.ui-li-divider):hidden').length) {
        $listItems.show();
    } else {
        $listItems.hide();
    }

});
```

*jsfiddle:*
http://jsfiddle.net/Lrhebm2z/

***Update:***

code for id `com-status-value`

```
var $listItems = $('#com-status-value li:not(.ui-li-divider)');

$('#expand-collapse').on("click", function () {

    if ($('#com-status-value li:not(.ui-li-divider):hidden').length) {
        $listItems.show();
    } else {
        $listItems.hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: Alex, thanks for the help on the button.. Unfortunatley, I can't get mine to  work (I added the code & button, but it doesn't toggle the content?) This is the jsfiddle that I'm actually modeling: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4mPNj/ (except mine uses dynamic data & divider values)

Comment: On your jsfiddle you have `<ul id="hp-latest-articles"` but on your ColdFusion code you have `<ul id="com-status-value"` so try to grab the `$listItems` using the right id for your code.

Comment: thanks for the tip & update.. I checked &  I'm using "com-status-value" for all of my elements. I must be missing something..?

Comment: updated answer, check that you have `com-status-value` in the 2 places (line 1 and line 3)

Comment: everything updated with your latest.. press the "Expand/Collapse" button, it doesn't do anything? this is crazy... the only difference between your jsfiddle & my code is my listview section... it must be something there?

Comment: try to grab the `ul` first with `$('#com-status-value')`. What happens when you run `$('#com-status-value')` in the console?

Comment: init [ul#com-status-value.ui-listview, context: document, selector: "#com-status-value"]
0
:
ul#com-status-value.ui-listview
context
:
document
length
:
1
selector
:
"#com-status-value"
__proto__
:
Object(0)

Comment: next check your dividers have a class of `ui-li-divider`

Comment: added in a that class to my <li data-role="list-divider" data-filter="true" class="ui-li-divider">.... no change?

Comment: Alex, as an alternative.. do you see a way to make the list "Collapsed" by default..  http://jsfiddle.net/Lrhebm2z/

Comment: run `$listItems.hide();` at start, but you need to grab them first. With jQuery should be easy once you have the right id and classes in place. Use the console to select the elements step by step, there is no reason this should not work as long as you grab the right things.

Comment: Alex, thank you for the help.. but I've not been able to get this to work.. sorry I'm not familiar enough with doing your step by step suggestions.. one thing I noticed is that I have an extra nested <li> section where you only have one?